# Change Index Settings Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to automate a process in Access, and one of the steps I wish to automate is changing the Indexing settings of certain fields in my tables. I need to do this to increase the speed of subsequent queries (the query is about 100x faster with the indexing).

In any case, suppose my table, called "Cars", looks like this:

```
ID    Name                 Character     
1     Paul Newman          Doc Hudson
2     Larry the Cable Guy  Mater
3     Owen Wilson          McQueen
4     Joe Ranft            Red
```

I want to use VBA to change the index settings of "ID" and "Character" from "No" to "Yes (No Duplicates)".

This table does not exist initially.  It is created by a query and then I need to index the table and run more queries on it.

Comment: Even though the VBA solution to this task exists, I seriously doubt the practical value of this question. Setting index on Access Table Field is a matter of couple mouse clicks (it has an excellent visual QBE). Once done, it works forever. So, what is the point of VBA automating this mouse click? It's a complexity level added just for the sake of complexity. Start with data modeling first, set all Tables, indices, relationships, then add your VBA stuff upon necessity - this is the right sequence of Access development.  Thanks and regards,

Comment: Yeah, I got it. as I said - do not create a Table dynamically via VBA, create it manually (MS Access has an excellent visual tools) and then update just Data (using VBA cmd. command for example). It's a way more simple than deleting Table and then recreating it via VBA (for e.g., the query DELETE * FROM [THAT_TABLE] do the job) than doing otherwise. Best regards,

Comment: That is some strange cars - not known on this side of the planet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was simply to execute these 2 SQL statements:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Index1 ON Cars (ID)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Index2 ON Cars (Character)
```

That did the trick.  This is a simple solution.