# Automatic method of leaving Indexed value = YES in Microsoft Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm referencing 1 single table as output from multiple query updates. Is there a way to force this table to always have the Indexed value remaining TRUE for specified fields? The issue is because the table's fields get modified after execution of each type of query and I currently have to click and change the Indexed fields to "Yes" before executing the next query.

This Indexed property in Microsoft Access helped resolve my issue with processing power for the thread below:
[Exclude Certain Records with Certain Values SQL Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983582/exclude-certain-records-with-certain-values-sql-select?noredirect=1#comment65322314_38983795)

Answer (score 0):

This does it:
[Change Index Settings Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720777/change-index-settings-access-vba)

Change it to below if duplicate values are required (removing the UNIQUE keyword):
`CREATE INDEX Index1 ON Cars (ID)`